# pip 23.2 fails installation for local files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, proxy

I am behind a firewall, so I need to open a proxy to do this, however this is what's bugging me... the example of beautifulsoup4 is just an example, this happens with any package:

```
create a new venv with python 3.10 or above

pip install --upgrade pip --proxy=....

pip install beautifulsoup4 --proxy=....  ## SUCCESS installed beautifulsoup4.12.2

pip uninstall beautifulsoup4

wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/0b/44c39cf3b18a9280950ad63a579ce395dda4c32193ee9da7ff0aed547094/beautifulsoup4-4.12.2.tar.gz

tar -xvf beautifulsoup4-4.12.2.tar.gz

pip install ./beautifulsoup4-4.12.2  --proxy=....  ##  FAIL with  http / ssl connection issues
```

the error I get is always similar to this, with the name of the package changing

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/setuptools/
```

which results in

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

it's like when downloading a package from pypi (success above) it's fine, but when installing locally it fails to fetch the dependencies from pypi.

this did not happen before pip 23.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, it was solved by applying an http url to the https proxy at os level, while also using --proxy flag and http address in pip. This was a long try and error, but it works now.

in short:

```
export {http,https}_proxy="http://$(PROXY_IP):8080" 
pip install -r requirements.txt --proxy=http://$(PROXY_IP):8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need proxy argument to install a .tar package from a local directory. Having said that... If this is the case where the package has missing dependencies that needs to be installed, you have to their installation separately.

Furthermore, you could try to use:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package to install>
```

...If this is a HTTP/SSL cert firewall problem.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: nope, it doesn't work... I tried installing the dependencies but it still hangs, and trusted-host does not make a difference. I am starting to think if this is a bug , given it wasn't happening on previous versions